# Error don't show title and image in meta tag for SEO in pure ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, reactjs.net

`I am using pure Reactjs,. I added meta tag to display title and image for SEO. I checked on elements` of Chrome tool dev and saw that there was a new meta added, but I didn't see it on Network, and when `I sent the link, I didn't see the title and the image attached to the link. does anyone know the` solution? Thank.

`Please see attached image:`  [check in Facebook developement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjwbg.png)
`[render see in Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCeTI.png)` [see in Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3wbu.png)

`I tried with Helmet library but it didn't get the result I wanted``

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.